# Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, transformation

Good Day! I,m aware of the basic concept of mean value theorem but the application of it in proving makes me confuse, this is how it goes:

By mean Value theorem:
$$2 - t^{n-1} (1+t) = (1 - t)[θ^{n – 1}  + (n - 1) θ^{n – 2}  (1 + θ)$$
                    $$ < (2n - 1)(1 + t)$$
where $$t < θ < 1$$

How does it happen? I have no idea.... I think this is complex form of mean value theorem...Any idea would be a great help thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do with the mean value theorem?

Comment: @Abel Sir, the I think the proof is trying to approximate an initial formula into its integrable form..since the initial formula cannot be integrate directly.

Comment: rosa, what is the initial formula?

Comment: @Abel $$\frac{4}{\pi} \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1-t^{2})^{2} - \frac {(n+1)(t^{2n}}{(1 - t^{2n+2})^{2}}$$

Comment: @Abel $$\frac{4}{\pi} \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1-t^{2})^{2}} - \frac {(n+1)(t^{2n})}{(1 - t^{2n+2})^{2}}}$$

Comment: rosa, i posted what i think you are looking for. let me know if i am on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you are applying the mean value theorem to the function $$ f(x) = x^{n-1}(1+x)=x^{n-1}+x^n, \, f'(x) = (n-1)x^{n-2}+nx^{n-1} $$ on the closed interval $[t, 1].$

we get $$f(1) - f(t)=f'(\theta) \text{ for some } \theta \in (t, 1.)$$

that is $$ 2- t^{n-1}(1+t) = (1-t)\left((n-1)\theta^{n-2}+n\theta^{n-1}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir I'll study your solution tnx a lot!

:)

Comment: May I add sir? How did $$(1 - t)[θ^{n – 1}  + (n - 1) θ^{n – 2}  (1 + θ)]$$become less than
                    $$  (2n - 1)(1 + t)?$$